# RadUpload doesn't work in EditFormSettings (WebUserControl) in RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radupload

In a nutshell, I have **RadGrid** with edit form with type of WebUserControl.

```
   <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server">
    <telerik:RadGrid ...>

    <Columns>
    ...
    </Columns>
    <EditFormSettings UserControlName=".../EditForm.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
    </EditFormSettings>

    </MasterTableView>

    </telerik:RadGrid>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

EditForm contains **RadUpload** control. The problem is: in OnUpdateCommand UploadedFiles of RadUpload all time is empty. I can't get and save uploaded file.

Comment: Have you tried removing the AJAX panel and replacing it with an `<asp:Panel>`? It's been my experience that file uploads won't work when you don't do a full post back.

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/1717855